# Using the Distribution Function Technique and then linking it to the normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have $Z$ as a standard random variable (with zero mean and unit variance), for all $t≥0$ and $X_t=\sqrt t Z$

I need to find the distribution function ${F_X}_t = P(X≤ x)$ and then show that $X_t $ ~ $ N(0:t)$ for all $t ≥0$ which in essence is me finding that $X_t$ is a normally distributed variable with variance t and zero mean.

So far I have done:
${F_X}_t (x) = P(X_t ≤x)=P(\sqrt t Z ≤x)=P(t≤ (\frac{x}{z})^2$

From here would I then integrate $(\frac{x}{z})^2$ between the bounds of t ?

Am I on the right lines? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, when plugging in $\sqrt{t}Z$ for $X_t$ solve for $Z$ instead of $t$. This should get you on the right track.

Comment: You want it in terms of Z not t. Then write as integral and differentiate, and compare to PDF of $N(0,t)$

Comment: You should take $t>0$. It doesn't work for $t=0$.

Comment: Thank you both that clears things up,  I have followed the integration steps and achieved $2x \sqrt t$, how would I show that this is a random distribution with 0 mean and unit variance?

Answer (score 1):

In general if $U$ is a random variable and $V=cU$ where $c$ is a *positive* constant then $$F_V(x)=P(V\leq x)=P(cU\leq x)=P(U\leq x/c)=F_U(x/c)$$

Comment: Thank you, I have followed this process to achieve $2x \sqrt t $, do you have a suggestion for how I can show that it is equivalent to the normal distribution

Comment: It is unclear to me how to achieve $2x\sqrt{t}$. In your question I read that $Z$ is a standard random variable. What do you mean by that? I mean: what is the distribution (or CDF) of $Z$?